# Kotlin drawable android path data

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I am new to Kotlin development and my proffesors don't really know much about Kotlin and handling its files.

I am trying to make my first app and I am trying to create different sections in menu sidebar so that i can redirect to different pages when the option is clicked. By default, android studio has 3 prebuilt options. I made a drawable file simmilar to the one which was built for the default once but i am not sure how I can find or write the `android:pathData`.

[Fragment I created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzbof.png)

In this image, i have made a new fragment with new name and stuff.

[Drawable file I made for the new fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIFvW.png)

i made this drawablw file for new segment but i am not sure how i can link both and what to write in the android:pathData section.

This is my first time and I dont have much knowlwdge about the vocabulary I should use sorry if you didnt get my question.

Comment: Path data is for imported vector drawables. It’s too complicated to write by hand. It can be created by importing an SVG file as a vector asset. If you want to design some vector shapes by hand, create a ShapeDrawable instead. You can Google that to get the instructions for how the different elements are defined in XML. Your question has nothing to do with Kotlin. An Android app is made up of resources defined in XML and code written in any of a few different languages, Kotlin being one of them. Kotlin isn’t used exclusively for Android, either.

Comment: Resources defined in XML in this specific way are an Android thing, not a Kotlin thing. You wouldn’t be usi them if writing something in Kotlin for platforms other than Android.